# Creating a slider between two numbers

Tags: javascript

So I've been working on re-producing the slider found here https://www.skylight.io/ ( Scroll down to find the price slider ).
So far Ive managed to create something similiar, but some numbers are hard coded, making it difficult to change and not very re-usable.
I've been researching around and I think I need to use Math.log() and Math.exp() together to achieve something like in the link above but I'm not sure.

Heres a jsfiddle of what I have so far https://jsfiddle.net/7wrvpb34/.

I feel that its the maths part of this problem that is halting me I think, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Javascript code below:

```
var slider = document.getElementById("slider")
var sliderFill = document.getElementById("slider-fill")
var knob = document.getElementById("knob")

var mouseDown;
var mousePos = {x:0};
var knobPosition;

var minPrice = 20;
var price = 0;
var minRequests = 50;
var requests = 50 + ",000";

var incrementSpeed = 2;
var incrementModifier = 20;
var incrementValue = 1;

var minMillionCount = 1;
var millionCount = 1;

var previousRequestAmount = 0;

document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
document.getElementById("requests").innerHTML = requests;

highlightTable(1);

document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    if(mouseDown) {
        updateSlider(e);
    }
})

function updateSlider(event) {
    mousePos.x = event.clientX - slider.getBoundingClientRect().left;
    mousePos.x -= knob.offsetWidth / 2;

    console.log(mousePos.x);

    if(mousePos.x < 0) {
        knob.style.left = "0px";
        sliderFill.style.width = "0px";
        price = 0;
        requests = 50 + ",000";
        document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
        document.getElementById("requests").innerHTML = requests;
        return
    }
    if(mousePos.x > slider.offsetWidth - 20) {
        return
    }
    sliderFill.style.width = mousePos.x +  10 + "px";
    knob.style.left = mousePos.x + "px";
    //Increase requests by using X position of mouse
    incrementSpeed = mousePos.x / incrementModifier;
    requests = minRequests + (mousePos.x * incrementSpeed);
    //Round to nearest 1
    requests = Math.round(requests / incrementValue) * incrementValue;
    if (requests >= 1000){
        var m = requests/ 1000;
        m = Math.round(m / 1) * 1;
        //Problem, lower the modifier depending on requests
        incrementModifier = 20 * 0.95;
        document.getElementById("requests").innerHTML = m + " million";
        //Adjust Prices
        if(( requests >= 1000) && (requests < 10000)) {
            var numOfMillions = requests / 100;
            //Round to closest 10.
            //10 * number of millions
            var rounded = Math.round(numOfMillions / 10) * 10;
            price = minPrice + rounded;
            highlightTable(3);
        }
        //Adjust Prices
        if(requests >= 10000) {
            var numOfMillions = requests / 1000;
            var rounded = Math.round(numOfMillions / 1) * 1;
            var basePrice = minPrice * 6;
            price = basePrice + rounded;
            highlightTable(4);
        }
    } else {
        incrementModifier = 20;
        document.getElementById("requests").innerHTML = requests + ",000"
        if(requests < 100) {
            highlightTable(1);
            price = 0;
        } else {
            highlightTable(2);
            price = 20;
        }
    }
    previousRequestAmount = requests;
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = price;
}

knob.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
    mouseDown = true;
});

document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
    mouseDown = false;
});


function highlightTable(rowNum) {
    var table = document.getElementById("payment-table")
    for(var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; ++i) {
        var row = table.rows[i]
        if(i == rowNum) {
            row.style.background = "grey"
        } else {
            row.style.background = "white";
        }

    }
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have a concrete question?

Comment: Apologies for the vagueness, What I'm asking is what mathematical ways are there of achieving a slider that can have a min and max number 'requests', and which increments increasingly depending on the current value of 'requests', If that makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be reusable you need to create a mathematical function that assigns a result to the number of requests. I will give you a very easy example.

If you want a different result for 1,10,100,100,10000 etc

```
var d = Math.log10(requests);

if(d<1){
 doSomething();
}else if(d<2){
 doSomethingElse();
} //etc
```

This way if you want to change the specific values that create certain results, all you need to do is change the function.

This only works if your tiers of requests follow a math function, if they don't you need to hard code it.

However if say they don't follow a math function, but you know how you would like them to change based on a value then you can do this.

```
var changingValue = 4;

if(requests < 400*changingValue){
 doSomthing();
}else if(requests <= 400*changingValue*changingValue){
 doSomethingElse();
}else{// the requests is greater than any of the above
 doTheOtherThing();
}
```

Edit:

For the second one you need to make sure that each condition if always larger than the other from top to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The description "increasingly increasing" matches an arbitrary number of functions. I assume you also want it to be *continuous*, since you already have a non-continuous solution.

#### TL;DR

Use an exponential function.

#### Generic approach

Assuming `imin` and `imax` are the minimal and maximal values of the slider (`i` for input) and `omin` and `omax` are the minimal and maximal values to be displayed, the simplest thing I can think of would be a multiplication by something based on the input value:

```
f(x)
{
    return omin + (omax - omin) * g((x - imin) / (imax - imin));
}
```

This will pass `0` to `g` if `x == imin` and `1` if `x == imax`.
The return value `r` of `g(y)` should be

```
r == 0    for y == 0
r == 1    for y == 1
0 < r < y for 0 < y < 1
```

The simplest function that I can think of that fulfills this is an exponential function with exponent > 1.
An exponent of 1 would be a linear function.
An exponent of 2 would be make the middle of the slider display one fourth of the maximum price instead of half of it.
But you really need to find that exponent yourself, based on *your* needs.